# How can I manually increment an uniqueidentifier field like integer in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

```
declare @id uniqueidentifier
set @id = '0D20697B-1D3C-4440-9BD1-00158D54B690'
set @id = @id + 1
select @id
```

**Error Message :**

> The data types uniqueidentifier and varchar are incompatible in the
>   add operator.

I want it to work. How?

Comment: I need to use many IDs in 3 same platforms. I have one script to insert. I want all of the IDs be same. Auto increment can not be used in my platform because there are already many data inserted. I also can not change base database

Comment: @MdAhsanulKabir: Can you show us your script, how you gonna use `@id` in your script ?

Comment: Maybe `NEWID()` will be more appropriate in your case...

Comment: I can not use newid() because it randomly generates different IDs in different time

Comment: I can not share my script because it is controversial. Just think I need a lot of IDs to insert in different platforms and I want all of them to be same. Suppose, I have a 'person' table. And I have a row containing 'Krishnraj Rana'. I want his ID be same in all of the platforms. If I use newid(), then problem won't be solved. At the same time I can not use autoincrement because I don't have access to change basic structure of database and secondly All of the platforms don't have same last ID of 'person' table

Comment: Are you saying you are trying to substitute newid function? Am I correct that you wish to implement some kind of synchronized generator, init it with the same value one different "platforms" expecting that serially inserted rows will obtain same id on independent servers?

Comment: @MdAhsanulKabir: Well i think you can use `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`. So what you can do is just add default constraint in PK column of your main table like this - `id uniqueidentifier primary Key DEFAULT (NEWSEQUENTIALID())` because it generates values in sequential order as opposed to `NewID()`. Then insert into that table and get the last sequential id into one variable and then use that variable to insert in another table. For exa. `Insert into Person(seqID, Name) Values (@SeqID, 'Ahsanul Kabir')`.....

Comment: @Krishnraj Rana I can not change table. I can only insert

Comment: You are right @Ivan Starostin

Comment: This is a very bed idea. Nature of GUID is "no sense and no order" and the core of it is `newid` function which guarantees unique result produced regarding specific algorithm. So trying to "increase with 1" (whatever result will look like) you ruin the idea of using GUID for purpose of uniqueness. And how did you image to keep this counter synchronized across many servers? Nobody inserts anything on other servers? If someone inserts a row on a server - counter will have to be increased. Somebody else inserts another row on another server - counter will be increased there too.

Comment: Rows are different but identifier is the same 'cause guid is broken.

Comment: Can you describe how are rows migrated across servers? You want same row to have same guid on different servers - how does this row get on other servers (other platforms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE  @ID                      VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Hex                     VARBINARY(16),
        @hexString               VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @ID = 'AAA6F580-98C8-42D0-8ACA-21C87589B1F7' --newid

SET @hexString = '0x'+RIGHT(@ID,4)
SET @ID = Left(@ID,32) + RIGHT(UPPER(master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr (CONVERT(VARBINARY(16), CONVERT(INT, (select cast('' as xml).value('xs:hexBinary( substring(sql:variable("@hexString"), sql:column("t.pos")) )', 'varbinary(max)')
from (select case substring(@hexString, 1, 2) when '0x' then 3 else 0 end) as t(pos))) + 1))),4)

select @ID
```